# Flash XML error

Tags: xml, flash

I'm using the following code to get something through XML

```
var myLoader:URLLoader;
var myXML:XML;
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://testapp.varheroes.com/yofacebook/canvas/calcammo/");

myXMLURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myLoader= new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);


function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    dummyText.text = myXML.AMMO;
}
```

When I test the code offline it works perfectly fine but when I put it on the webpage

http://media.varheroes.com/flash/as3.swf

It stops working :/

Running it offline gives me this XML, which I can put in a text field

```
<MAIN><AMMO>54564564564564564545464564564564</AMMO></MAIN>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Please provide additional information.

Comment: No I don't get an error. The text just does not show. If I try it offline it works. The XML url when tested in browser is also working. 

XML just doesn't show any output when put online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for cross domain xml if your xml file is out of your application.

Comment: could you elaborate on that? 

I tried testing my XMLurl it works 
    http://testapp.varheroes.com/yofacebook/canvas/calcammo/

Comment: Read this, should make things clearer: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html